# how can i do a OR query in ruby mongo?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I used this in the MongoDB console:

```
db.video.find( { $or : [ { "tags" : /pePe/i } , { "title" : /.*Aubrey.*/i } ] } )
```

and it works fine.

How can I do this query in Ruby?

Comment: Are you using mongo-mapper, mongoid or mongo-driver?

Answer (score 9):

Using the Mongo Driver:

```
require 'mongo'
connect  = Mongo::Connection.new
database = connect['development']

database['video'].find({ :$or => [{:tags => /pePe/i}, {:title => /.*Aubrey.*/i}] })
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mongoid that's

`Video.where( :$or => [{:tags => /pePe/i}, {:title => /.*Aubrey.*/i}] )`

Assuming you have model named Video that points to video collection (which is default).

Mongo driver should act [exactly the same way](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html#Getting_a_Set_of_Documents_With_a_Query) except for `.find` instead of `.where`.